# Cannot Access localhost on Wamp Server(3.06) using 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am getting the WAMP server page using localhost fine.
But when using 127.0.0.1 in Chrome I am getting

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 took too long to respond.
```

In Mozilla I am getting

```
The connection has timed out
The server at 127.0.0.1 is taking too long to respond.
```

So error is similar.

httpd.conf setting are like this:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

httpd-vhosts.conf is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot e:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "e:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file contents:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost
```

update response for ping in CMD:

```
C:\Users\pkj>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: did you check that wamp is working ? most probably skype using port 80 and 443

Comment: @RooshanAkthar wamp is working because the OP said that localhost loads fine

Comment: @Pawan , try open your CMD and `ping 127.0.0.1` take a screenshot and add it here

Comment: You are doing this on the PC running WAMPServer right? Not from another PC on your network?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes I am doing this on the PC running Wampserver. Not from another PC on network.

Comment: Ahh I see you say you are using Chrome. Have you tried this with any other browser? Chrome has odd issues with localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I have given response for both chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: You could try clearing your browser cache (CTRL+F5)

Comment: I have tried that. even tried in incognito mode. Nothing helps when trying to access using 127.0.0.1

Comment: As already stated, may be port 80 is used by skype. Did you tried to listen port 81?

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis - If there is problem in port 80. The I assume, I won't be able to access Localhost. which loads fine.

Comment: This has worked in the past, but Chrome seems to get issues like this quite often and it may be an old solution. Go to `chrome://flags` and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I coudn't locate in `chrome://flags` any setting for "Built-in Asynchronous DNS"

Comment: Yea I cannot either now I look, must have been for an older version. I am just going through all the Chrome issue/fix notes I have

Answer (score 0):

In the past this has also solved a Chrome issue or 2

Do this from a command window started using `Run as Administrator`

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then reboot if necessary.

Comment: Hi - I have run the commands in the order it is mentioned and restarted the PC in all instances except the last one. Now I am having new problem, that my `WAMP server` stays Orange.

Comment: Ok - If I change the port to 8080, I am able to start the WAMP. Can't say what happened in between those commands. But now I am not able to start WAMP using port 80. 
Now I am able to access localhost like localhost:8080.
127.0.0.1 is still not working.
I noticed one thing which might resolve the problem is that, when I ping localhost- the reply is from `::1` and when I ping 127.0.0.1 the reply is from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Looks like wamp server localhost not able to resolve to IPV4 address.

Comment: `::1` is normally the default network things try to use now, in preparation for when IPV4 gets turned off